# C++ simulate physical audio output

Tags: software, audio-engineering

I am searching for help with simulating a physical audio device and get its input from the OS (mainly Windows and Linux). Couldn't find any information about this so far. The idea is to block the default audio output device, simulate one, get the actual audio output and transmit it over the local network. Would really appreciate ideas on how I can realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On a linux system, all devices are items in the filesystem. Ther're organized under /dev

You can do read and write operations on them. Hence, reading from an audio device is just reading from the "file". Try "ll /dev/snd" to enumerate available devices.

I am not sure, but you may get away without programming, if you pip the output of you device on one computer into a device on the other computer, with just system tool.

On windows: I don't know. Probably way more complicated, but others may know better.